# How this limit prove the Frechet Distribution has Heavy Tails?

Tags: limits, distribution-tails, extreme-value-theorem, extreme-value-analysis

First, we start from the GEV-distribution function:

> **Theorem 1.1.3 (Fisher and Tippett (1928), Gnedenko (1943))** *The class of extreme value fistributions is $G_\gamma(ax+b)$ with $a>0$, $b$ real, where$$G_\gamma(x)=\exp\left(-(1+\gamma x)^{-1/\gamma}\right),\,\quad1+\gamma x>0,\quad(1.1.9)$$with $\gamma$ real and where for $\gamma=0$ the right-hand side is interpreted as* $\exp(-e^{-x})$.

Then when we set gamma>0, we get the Frechet distribution, and my book says:

> (a) For $\gamma>0$ clearly $G_\gamma(x)<1$ for all $x$, i.e., the right endpoint of the distribution is infinity. Moreover, as $x\to\infty$, $1-G_\gamma(x)\sim\gamma^{-1/\gamma}x^{-1/\gamma}$, i.e., the distribution has a rather heavy right tail; for example, moments of order greater than or equal to $1/\gamma$ do not exist (cf. Exercise 1.16).

But how do they come to the part of $1 - G(x) \sim\gamma^{-1/\gamma}x^{-1/\gamma}$ when $x\to\infty$?

Comment: A policy explained [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards) requires users to refrain from answering a question about an encountered difficulty until it clarifies what the author attempted & why it was unhelpful. This helps pinpoint what would be of most help. ([This page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), to which it links twice, provides more detail on what makes a question easier to answer.)

Comment: Are you aware of the small-$u$ asymptotic behaviour of $1-\exp(-u)$?

Comment: No i am not, can you help me out?

Comment: What is your definition of $\exp$?

Comment: The natural exponential exponential function

Comment: No, I mean _which_ definition of $\exp u$ can I use as a starting point when proving theorems about it? For example, can I use its derivative, or maybe its Taylor series?

Comment: I would say the limit relation of exp(u), exp(x) = (1+x/n)^n as n goes to inf

Comment: Ah, I was so focused on the limit relation with $n \rightarrow \infty$(which is not the case) that I missed the relation with the Taylor series. Saw this in another textbook about the Generalized Pareto Distribution. The 'trick' is that as $x \rightarrow  \infty,$ the CDF of x ($G_\gamma (x)$  in this case) goes to 1, s.t. only the first term of the Taylor series is of importance.

Thanks @J.G.

Comment: To be formal, $1-\exp(-u)\sim u$ (i.e. $1-\exp(-u)$ *is asymptotic to* $u$).